zatca The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method
protected void ButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://gw-fatoora.zatca.gov.sa/e-invoicing/developer-portal/compliance");

    request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");
    request.Headers.Add("OTP", "123345");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Version", "V2");

    request.Content = new StringContent("{\n  \"csr\": \"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\"\n}");
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}

I get this compilation error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.


I think you need to share the method signature too. Because it says you need to change your method to an async method which returns a Task. Your method should look like: "public async Task YourMethod(string yourParameter)"

i don't have method signature, i convert code from curl to c# but i got this error after convert

What is zatca? Where is this code in your application?

protected void ButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) is a method signature. It needs to change to be async.

Can you write me the code in the correct way to run the code when Click a button? Please

"Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'"? If you're not sure what the async keyword is, it's probably not a good idea to copy paste in async code when you don't know how it works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async

Please, do everyone a favor and read some of the documentation available on the internet. Microsoft has a lot resources for learning, about using HttpClient correctly too that you may wish to look at.

You can use ".Result" suffix for awaitable functions.
In your case
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;```

@Ramazan careful with .Result, it may cause a deadlock. It's better to make the method async

Adding the async modifier to your method and chaging its return type to Task will fix your issue. You cannot call asynchronous methods within a synchronous method.
protected async Task ButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // rest of your code
}

I also recommend reading the Microsoft documentation about asynchronous programming, because understanding the difference between asynchronous and synchronous programming is vital.
